# vb.net external-only properties or methods

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, recursion, namespaces, public

Is there a simple way in vb.net to mask a public property or method from the internal namespace?  It would be helpful as a refactoring tool to isolate internal dependencies and perhaps to enforce a non-recursion policy for external services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Any property or method that's usable from the external world is usable from your internal project as well, by definition.

Some tools, such as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), though, can simplify checking policies like this.  For example, Resharper lets you view an entire list of call sites where a property or method is being used.  You could use this to verify that nothing internal is using a specific method.

Answer (score 0):

As Reed said, there is no way to do this in VB.Net (or C# for that matter).

Another approach you could take is to use multiple assemblies.  Essentially put the two logical components into different assemblies and use that boundary as a means to enforce the policy at hand.  You can even use a tool like ILMerge to combine the assemblies back into a single one at a later point.